# Alternate way for setting permissions for J2me application

Tags: java-me, midp, j2mepolish, jsr82

Currently I am using jad to set the http and Bluetooth permissions.

But I have a problem with this approach. Some of the handsets does not have support for 
bluetooth API, so the phone is not allowing the installation of the application as it does not support the bluetooth API.

Is there any alternate way of setting these permissions?

Comment: This will be the soln: MIDlet-Permissions-Opt: javax.microedition.io.Connector.bluetooth.client This is how u can specify optional permission.

Comment: Yes, its working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
MIDlet-Permissions-Opt: javax.microedition.io.Connector.bluetooth.client
```

This is how you can specify optional permission.

Answer (score 1):

If a handset does not have Bluetooth API then the Java Virtual Machine does not have javax.bluetooth package. Because of this the handset may not allow you to install the app.

Create another version of your app without any usage of the javax.bluetooth package and try installing again.

Comment: This will be the soln: MIDlet-Permissions-Opt: javax.microedition.io.Connector.bluetooth.client                       This is how u can specify optional permission.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to specify these permissions at all. The MIDlet will work properly without them.

Comment: This will be the soln: MIDlet-Permissions-Opt: javax.microedition.io.Connector.bluetooth.client This is how u can specify optional permission.